# FIND LOGIC FOR SORTING DATAS

Tags: sas

I am a beginner in SAS and I have some datelines as

```
VIT_A 12 23 22 0 32 0 11
VIT_C 10 9 0 21 0 26 76
```

[image: a]

if I want to list only the datas where `VIT_A ^=0` , `VIT_C^=0` what will be the logic?

Results will be

```
VIT_A 12 23 22 32 11
VIT_C 10 9 21 26 76
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site.  You need to reformat your data I suspect so that the columns and rows are clear; and then take a look at a beginning SAS tutorial/text.  It isn't clear from the above whether you actually have one dataset or two datasets; we don't have vectors in base SAS, among other things, so it's unclear exactly what your data structure is like.

Comment: Are the values saved in rows or columns? How does your table look like?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply VIT_A and VIT_C are variables (they are in columns and the numbers are the datas displayed in rows)

Comment: Does your data look like this : row 1 `VIT_A 12 23 22 0 32 0 11` or this row 1 `VIT_A 12` row 2 `VIT_A  23` .. etc ?

Comment: There's no attachment

Comment: @momo1644 Images can't be attached by very new posters to avoid spam/etc.

Comment: @DILIPKUMAR I will reiterate that I think you aren't understanding some core SAS concepts, and are thinking more like an R or Matlab programmer with these as vectors.  You simply wouldn't do something like this in SAS.

Comment: @Joe Hi, Thanks for your feedback, I think I have not explained the question clearly. My datas are simple as VIT_A and VIT_C are in column1 and column2 respectively and values like 12 23 22 0 32 0 11 are under VIT_A in each rows ,same for VIT_C(Values are below VIT_C as 10 9 21 26 76). But I like to have the results without "0" value in the same pattern as VIT_A and VIT_C in columns and values are under them respectively. Is that possible?. Is there any logic to fetch the result?

Comment: @momo1644 Hi Thanks, it worked.  Thanks everyone for your answers.

Comment: Great. I am happy you found my answer useful.  Please approve the answer so the Question gets closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data looks like this Table **[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N19EZ.png)**:

```
    COL1    COL2
1   VIT_A   VIT_C
2   12     10
3   23     9
4   22     0
```

You just need to used a `where` clause

If your data looks like this Table **[2]**:

```
    COL1                  COL2
1   VIT_A                 VIT_C
2   12 23 22 0 32 0 11    10 9 0 21 0 26 76
```

Then you can use `tranwrd` function to replace  `' '`  with `','` then replace `'0'` with `''`

Solution for table **[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N19EZ.png)**:

Data:

```
data have;
input VIT_A  VIT_C;
datalines;
12 10
23 9
22 0
0 21
3 20
0 26
11 76
;
run;
```

Create two new tables without any `0` values and add row number in as `obs`:

```
proc sql;
create table VIT_A as
select monotonic() as obs , VIT_A from have where VIT_A ne 0 ; 
create table VIT_C as
select monotonic() as obs ,VIT_C from have where VIT_C ne 0;
quit;
```

Merge the two tables:

```
data want;
merge VIT_A VIT_C;
by obs;
run;
```

Output:

```
 obs=1 VIT_A=12 VIT_C=10 
 obs=2 VIT_A=23 VIT_C=9 
 obs=3 VIT_A=22 VIT_C=21 
 obs=4 VIT_A=3 VIT_C=20 
 obs=5 VIT_A=11 VIT_C=26 
 obs=6 VIT_A=. VIT_C=76
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Can you please confirm, Is your data similar to table [1] or [2]? so I can give you a working SAS code.

Comment: hi Thanks for your effort. My data looks like table 1. The output also looks like the table 1 but without the value '0' in both VIT_A and VIT_C.

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose your data, then select none zero values into a macro variable.

Assuming the values are in columns not in rows:

```
data have;
length string $100. ;
format string $100. ;
input string $ v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7;
datalines;
VIT_A 12 23 22 0 32 0 11
VIT_C 10 9 0 21 0 26 76 
;
run;
proc transpose data=have out=trans name=value;
by string;
run;
proc sql noprint ;
select COL1 into :VIT_A separated by ' '  from trans where string="VIT_A" and COL1 <> 0;
select COL1 into :VIT_C separated by ' ' from trans where string="VIT_C" and COL1 <> 0;
quit;

Data Want;
string='VIT_A';
Values="&VIT_A.";
output;
string='VIT_C';
Values="&VIT_C.";
output;
run;
```

Output:

```
string=VIT_A Values=12 23 22 32 11
string=VIT_C Values=10 9 21 26 76
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? let me know if your input data is different. ex. How many rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a WHERE statement?

```
proc print data=have ;
  where vit_a ne 0 ;
run;
```

If you want to test multiple variables then make sure to combine them with the right logic.

```
where vit_a ne 0 AND vit_c ne 0;
```

Is different than

```
where vit_a ne 0 OR vit_c ne 0;
```

Comment: AND/OR condition will not satisfy my condition because it gives results if both variable ne 0 or either one ne 0 but I want to list the VIT_A values without '0' also VIT_C values without '0'.

Comment: You need to show what you want.  Do you want to exclude observations where either variable is zero?  `where NOT (vit_a=0 or vit_c=0);`

Comment: If you want to list them separately then run separate proc print steps.